# Android: select Tab programatic if in Dropdown List mode

Tags: android, user-interface

Depending on the number of tabs and on screen orientation tabs are displayed next to each other or in a dropdown list.
I wrote a function to set the current tab. This works but not in dropdown list mode. What has to be done?

```
static class TabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private static ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
...


public void setTab(int i) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);

    }
```

Comment: also tried mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i); no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to have the tab/drop-down selection change when the user swipes a tab, that will not work in drop-down mode, [due to a bug in `setSelectedNavigationItem()`](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38500). I am not aware of a workaround while still using tabs in the action bar. Personally, this is one of the reasons why I prefer `PagerTabStrip` (or the tab indicator from the ViewPagerIndicator library) over action bar tabs.

Comment: thanks for the info. i want to wait until a fix comes out. do you know how fast they provide updates?

Comment: @user1324936: I do not get the sense that this bug will be fixed any time soon. Jake Wharton's patch for it was rejected for some reason, and I have not seen any evidence that they are working on fixing it elsewhere. Also, since this pertains to the action bar, which is part of the OS from API Level 11 onward, it is quite likely that even if they fix the bug, it will only be fixed on newer versions of Android (e.g., a 4.2 or 5.0).